# Simple MySql update query very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Following query is taking very long time, although it should execute instantly:

```
mysql> UPDATE articles SET description='test' WHERE article_id=6;
Query OK, 1 row affected (40.80 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

- article_id is INT autoincrement
- table only has about 1000 records

I tried profiling the query, you can see it executes the update fast but then it hangs for some reason:

```
mysql> SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;
+----------------------+-----------+
| Status               | Duration  |
+----------------------+-----------+
| starting             |  0.000079 |
| checking permissions |  0.000016 |
| Opening tables       |  0.000020 |
| System lock          |  0.000011 |
| Table lock           |  0.000864 |
| init                 |  0.000078 |
| Updating             |  0.000315 |
| end                  | 40.798736 |
| query end            |  0.000028 |
| freeing items        |  0.000014 |
| closing tables       |  0.000012 |
| logging slow query   |  0.000010 |
| logging slow query   |  0.000046 |
| cleaning up          |  0.000012 |
+----------------------+-----------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried mounting the tmp directory to RAM, to speed up queries, but that did not help either.

I found that if I FLUSH the table, the problem goes temporarily away, but again it comes back after some time.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is anything else running against the database at the same time? You may be running into a locking issue, where some other query has locked the row in question.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved - turns out the mysql cache size was too large. Lowering it's size fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a MyISAM table you may want to repair it. I had this phenomenon with corrupt data files.

Comment: Yes, it is MyISAM. I tried REPAIR, OPTIMIZE and FLUSH many times. Only FLUSH fixes the problem, but even that just temporarily. Next day, the problem is back.

I should also mention that this is on a cluster of one master and one slave server, not sure if it has any relevance to the problem.